# Translating context to redux with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have this context:

```
interface AlertContextProps {
  show: (message: string, duration: number) => void;
}

export const AlertContext = createContext<AlertContextProps>({
  show: (message: string, duration: number) => {
    return;
  },
});

export const AlertProvider: FC<IProps> = ({ children }: IProps) => {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([]);

  const show = (message: string, duration = 6000) => {
    let alertKey = Math.random() * 100000;
    setAlerts([...alerts, <Alert message={message} duration={duration} color={''} key={alertKey} />]);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlerts(alerts.filter((i) => i.key !== alertKey));
    }, duration + 2000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {alerts}
      <AlertContext.Provider value={{ show }}>{children}</AlertContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

which I need to "translate" into a redux slice. I got a hang of everything, apart from the `show` method. What would be the correct way to treat it? I was thinking about a thunk, but it's not really a thunk. Making it a reducer with setTimeout also seems like an ugly thing to do. So how would you guys do it?

My code so far:

```
type Alert = [];

const initialState: Alert = [];

export const alertSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'alert',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAlertState(state, { payload }: PayloadAction<Alert>) {
      return payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setAlertState } = alertSlice.actions;
export const alertReducer = alertSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HMR's use of a thunk is fine, but I don't like what they've done to your reducer.  You're already using redux-toolkit which is great!  redux-toolkit actually includes and exports a `nanoid` function which they use behind the scenes to create unique ids for thunks.  You can use that instead of `Math.random() * 100000`.

I always start by thinking about types.  What is an `Alert`?  You don't want to store the `<Alert/>` because a `JSX.Element` is not serializable.  Instead you should just store the props.  You'll definitely store the `message` and `key`/`id`.  If you handle expiration on the front-end then you would also store the `duration`, but if the expiration is handled by a thunk then I don't think you need it in the redux state or component props.

It seems like you want to allow multiple alerts at one time, so `return payload` is not going to cut it for your reducer.  You'll need to store an array or a keyed object will all of your active alerts.

You absolute should not use `setTimeout` in a reducer because that is a side effect.  You can use it either in a thunk or in a `useEffect` in the `Alert` component.  My inclination is towards the component because it seems like the alert should probably be dismissible as well?  So you can use the same function for handling dismiss clicks and automated timeouts.

We can define the info that we want to store for each alert.

```
type AlertData = {
  message: string;
  id: string;
  duration: number;
}
```

And the info that we need to create that alert, which is the same but without the `id` because we will generate the id in the reducer.

```
type AlertPayload = Omit<AlertData, 'id'>
```

Our state can be an array of alerts:

```
const initialState: AlertData[] = [];
```

We need actions to add a new alert and to remove an alert once it has expired.

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
...

export const alertSlice = createSlice({
  name: "alert",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addAlert: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<AlertPayload>) => {
      const id = nanoid(); // create unique id
      state.push({ ...payload, id }); // add to the state
    },
    removeAlert: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      // filter the array -- payload is the id
      return state.filter((alert) => alert.id !== payload);
    }
  }
});

export const { addAlert, removeAlert } = alertSlice.actions;
export const alertReducer = alertSlice.reducer;
```

---

So now to the components.  What I have in mind is that you would use a selector to select all of the alerts and then each alert will be responsible for its own expiration.

```
export const AlertComponent = ({ message, duration, id }: AlertData) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // function called when dismissed, either by click or by timeout
  // useCallback is just so this can be a useEffect dependency and won't get recreated
  const remove = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(removeAlert(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  // automatically expire after the duration, or if this component unmounts
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(remove, duration);
    return remove;
  }, [remove, duration]);

  return (
    <Alert
      onClose={remove} // can call remove directly by clicking the X
      dismissible
    >
      <Alert.Heading>Alert!</Alert.Heading>
      <p>{message}</p>
    </Alert>
  );
};
```

```
export const ActiveAlerts = () => {
  const alerts = useSelector((state) => state.alerts);

  return (
    <>
      {alerts.map((props) => (
        <AlertComponent {...props} key={props.id} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

I also made a component to create alerts to test this out and make sure that it works!

```
export const AlertCreator = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(8000);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Create Alert</h1>
      <label>
        Message
        <input
          type="text"
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Duration
        <input
          type="number"
          step="1000"
          value={duration}
          onChange={(e) => setDuration(parseInt(e.target.value, 10))}
        />
      </label>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(addAlert({ message, duration }));
          setMessage("");
        }}
      >
        Create
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <AlertCreator />
    <ActiveAlerts />
  </div>
);
export default App;
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-expiring-alerts-injt5?file=/src/components/App.tsx)

Answer (score 2):

The timeout is a side effect so you could implement that in a [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).

You have an action that shows an alert message that has a payload of message, id and time to display, when that time runs out then the alert message needs to be removed so you need a remove alert message action as well that is dispatched from the thunk with a payload of the id of the alert message.

I am not sure why you add 2 seconds to the time to hide the message `duration + 2000` since the caller can decide how long the message should show I don't think it should half ignore that value and randomly add 2 seconds.

Here is a redux example of the alert message:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = {
  messages: [],
};
//action types
const ADD_MESSAGE = 'ADD_MESSAGE';
const REMOVE_MESSAGE = 'REMOVE_MESSAGE';
//action creators
const addMessage = (id, text, time = 2000) => ({
  type: ADD_MESSAGE,
  payload: { id, text, time },
});
const removeMessage = (id) => ({
  type: REMOVE_MESSAGE,
  payload: id,
});
//id generating function
const getId = (
  (id) => () =>
    id++
)(1);
const addMessageThunk = (message, time) => (dispatch) => {
  const id = getId();
  dispatch(addMessage(id, message, time));
  setTimeout(() => dispatch(removeMessage(id)), time);
};
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === ADD_MESSAGE) {
    return {
      ...state,
      messages: state.messages.concat(payload),
    };
  }
  if (type === REMOVE_MESSAGE) {
    return {
      ...state,
      messages: state.messages.filter(
        ({ id }) => id !== payload
      ),
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectMessages = (state) => state.messages;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      //simple implementation of thunk (not official redux-thunk)
      ({ dispatch }) =>
        (next) =>
        (action) =>
          typeof action === 'function'
            ? action(dispatch)
            : next(action)
    )
  )
);
const App = () => {
  const messages = useSelector(selectMessages);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch(addMessageThunk('hello world', 1000))
        }
      >
        Add message
      </button>
      <ul>
        {messages.map((message) => (
          <li key={message.id}>{message.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```